# How to undo transparent drawing?

Tags: android, canvas, drawing, android-canvas

I develop a drawing application. I need to implement undo and redo actions. It is necessary to implement undo by drawing same stroke over undoing stroke but with special paint. There are my paints for drawing and undoing:

```
val mainPaint = Paint().apply {
    color = Color.WHITE
    style = Paint.Style.STROKE
    alpha = 25
    xfermode = PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.ADD)
    isAntiAlias = true
  }

  val undoPaint = Paint().apply {
    color = Color.WHITE
    style = Paint.Style.STROKE
    alpha = 25
    xfermode = PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OUT)
    isAntiAlias = true
  }
```

First of all I draw first stroke by `mainPaint`:

[image]

Then I draw second stroke over the first by same `mainPaint`:

[image]

And finally I draw second stroke again, but with `undoPaint`, to implement undo:

[image]

As you can see, result doesn't looks like undo. After undo I expect state like on the first picture I attached. What I do wrong? What should I do to fix it? How must I build `undoPaint`?